# No puedo eliminar una relación many to many en django

Tags: django

Logré hacer la relación exactamente igual a esta función, pero con .add(menu), ahora al intentar eliminarlo simplemente no reacciona.

¿A que se podría deber?

```
def deletePlatoMenu(request,id_local,id_menu,id_plato):
    plato = Plato.objects.get(id=id_plato)
    menuu = Menu.objects.get(id=id_menu)
    plato.menu.remove(menuu)
    menuu.plato_set.remove(plato)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero verifica que de verdad si guardaste los cambios cuando agregaste los valores con .add Y por favor publica el error o se mas especifico